# How Laravel manages objects destructors?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a little experiment in Laravel Blade's view. I ran the simple PHP class in index.blade.php with constructor and destructor. I wonder how Laravel works that info from destructor (in my case is just echo) is always on the top of my page.

[image: Laravel's destructor behavior]

Normally PHP destructors should end with the end of script.

My code from Laravel (index.blade.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>User Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Test Demo</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
class User
{
    private $name = "Alex<br>";

    public function __construct() {
        echo "Constructor<br>";
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        echo "<br>Name from destructor:".$this->getName();
        echo "<br>Destructor";
    }
}

$TestUser = new User();
echo $TestUser->getName();

?>
```

Do you know why we have this behavior? How it works?

Comment: Laravel compiles blades and creates a different file that you can find under `project/framework/views` and runs that file instead of the blade. This is why you will have an `errorCode in randomstring.php` error if an error occurs on your blade instead of `in bladeName.blade.php`. I wonder if this has something to do with the weird behavior you're talking about.

Comment: I know that blade files aren't directly compiled but first changed to PHP. I think that I've figured it out. Answer below.

Comment: Oh sorry, for some reason I thought you stated you were new to laravel in the question. I do like your answer though.

Comment: Putting any significant code into a template file is a massive abuse of the concept of "separation of concerns" that is the whole reason we have template files in the first place. I get that the code in the question is an example for the purposes of demonstrating the problem, but if I ever saw a template file that looked like that submitted by one of my team members, I'd ask them to rewrite it.

Comment: @Spudley As I wrote in the first sentence it's just a little experiment. I'm aware of MVC and I wasn't going to create logic there as foundations of my project. I expected for comment like yours :) but I'm just interested in core.

Comment: @AleksanderTabor no worries  :-)  I could see it was a demo to show the problem, so I wasn't trying to tell you to fix it; you already know not to do this sort of thing normally, so that's great. My comment was really aimed at other visitors who might not know MVC so well who come to this question in the future and think this code is good. It needs to be clear for them that it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I know solution.

1. Laravel renders views.
2. All content saves in $contents (blade view + constructor).
3. Object from Blade's class still exists.
4. All content is in $contents.
5. Laravel quits render function.
6. Object deletes so destructor is called with echo.
7. Laravel displays $contents.

[image]